# Dia UML: create parent child relation betwen objects

Tags: gui, uml, dia

When using Dia to create an UML diagram, how to mark an object as the child of another object ?

Example:

- [One "big package"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYNV9.png)
- [One "object"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/870bU.png)

I would like to mark the object as the son of the package.

Answer (score 0):

### To add one (or more) child

1. Place the object(s) *inside* the package, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/borGt.png)
2. Select the future father and the future child (with a rectangular selection, or by holding shift while clicking)
3. Go to *Object* > *Adopt* or hit *Ctrl-K*

source: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/dia-list/2003-November/msg00007.html 
(I could not find help in the official documentation)

Comment: In my locality translation of Dia, this menu item is "Parent" (a shame, I think "Adopt" is more evocative of what it does).